# Sorting in Cassandra on primary key of type timeuuid

Tags: sorting, cassandra

I am new to cassandra. I want to get the sorted resultset on the basis of primary key i.e. timeuuid. My table stucture is.

```
CREATE TABLE user_session
(
  session_id timeuuid,
  ip inet,
  device_type int,
  is_active int,
  last_access_time timestamp,
  logout_reason text,
  logout_type int,
  start_time timestamp,  
  uid int,
  PRIMARY KEY(session_id)
);
```

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use order by in your query on primary column. It is only supported on clustering column. You would have to change this table so you can perform such a query. It might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_session
(
user_id int,
session_id timeuuid,
ip inet,
device_type int,
is_active int,
last_access_time timestamp,
logout_reason text,
logout_type int,
start_time timestamp,  
uid int,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, session_id)
);
```

Then, your query would look like:

```
select * from user_session where user_id=5 order by session_id ASC;
```

Basicaly, you need some primary key which will be used for searching data where only `EQ` and `IN` relations are allowed, so you can't have `user_id > 5` or something similar, and then you can order your results by on clustering column which is in your case `session_id`.

Zoran

Answer (score 1):

You can use ORDER BY from table definition in order to keep the correct order during insertions. The `PRIMARY KEY` definition has the partition key `user_id` and clustering column `session_id` which is used to sort. It might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_session
(
user_id int,
session_id timeuuid,
ip inet,
device_type int,
is_active int,
last_access_time timestamp,
logout_reason text,
logout_type int,
start_time timestamp,  
uid int,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, session_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (session_id ASC);
```